# Qt GUI application opens extra window when I start a thread (Windows)

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt5.5

I have Qt GUI application that uses boost and std built with Qt 5.5 I have written some API code that listens for requests (that why I moved API part to separate QThread). For Linux and Mac everything works perfectly. But on windows an extra window appears behind the main GUI app when I start a thread.

this is my worker class

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit Worker(int argc, char argv[], QObject parent = 0);

private:
int m_argc;
char* m_argv[7]; 

public slots:
    bool stop();
    void mainLoop();
};

and cpp

Worker::Worker(int argc, char argv[], QObject parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    m_argc = argc;
    m_argv[0] = argv[0];
    m_argv[1] = argv[1];
    m_argv[2] = argv[2];
    m_argv[3] = argv[3];
    m_argv[4] = argv[4];
    m_argv[5] = argv[5];
    m_argv[6] = argv[6];
}

bool Worker::stop()
{
return currency::stop_rpc();
}

void Worker::mainLoop()
{
qDebug()<<"Starting worker mainLoop in Thread "<<thread()->currentThreadId();

currency::run_wallet_rpc(m_argc, m_argv);
}
```

And this is how I start my thread

```
m_worker = new Worker(argc, argv);
m_rpc_thread = new QThread();

m_worker->moveToThread(m_rpc_thread);
connect(m_rpc_thread, SIGNAL(started()), m_worker, SLOT(mainLoop()));

m_rpc_thread->start();
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Have spent hours on this...

Comment: I have no idea where the window is coming from, but Qt's networking classes are all asynchronous. A separate thread is usually unnecessary, since you can handle communication inside slots. Is there a reason you really need the separate thread?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. We created the separate thread because we are not using callbacks, we're using an infinite loop

Comment: Is it possible that the slot for starting the thread is being triggered multiple times? You can check this by using a `qDebug()`. This is possible if you use `SIGNAL(pressed())` in a `QPushButton` instead of `clicked()`. Also, check for multiple connections.

Comment: Hi @Aditya no its only being triggered once, also we don't have buttons.